# Solution to hide a shared password to users

Tags: passwords, access-control

I am looking for a solution to a business / security need.

All our users use a shared login and password to access a web application.

- we cannot have an account by user
- we can not change the web application

I am looking for a solution to hide this login and password from users.

Is there a kind of proxy where a user connects with its own credential, to access the application, the proxy would make the authentification with the shared password?

This way the password does not need to be known by all users and can be managed in only one place; the proxy.

Comment: What you propose is possible to implement.  But, the exact implementation would depend on the specifics of the target site, i.e. how the login is handled there. I don't know if there is an existing product which helps you with this but product recommendations are off-topic anyway. Apart from that, sharing the same account by multiple users is not Single-Sign-On so I removed the sso tag you've used.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I'm seeing the question as more of a technique/technology question rather than a product recommendation. I have answered below as such.

Answer (score 3):

I have been where you are and had to deal with this kind of thing.

The technology type you are looking for is a Cloud Service Broker. It acts as a wrapper for external services that you can connect your local authentication services to. The service broker (depending on features) can then log in as a designated account to the external service.

This wrapper means that you get added security, auditing, the ability to lock someone out of the account (if they leave), while never exposing the service password.

Steffen is correct, though, whether or not you can use a CSB will depend on the target site.